# optional orElseThrow gives null pointer exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, option-type

I have this method:

```
public Tenant getTenant(String tenantId) throws TenantNotFoundException {
return tenantDatabaseService.findTenantById(tenantId)
    .orElseThrow(() -> new TenantNotFoundException("Tenant not found"));
}
```

`tenantDatabaseService.findTenantById(tenantId)` returns an `Optional`:

```
public Optional<Tenant> findTenantById(String id) {
    return tenantRepository.findById(id);
}
```

When `findById` is null, I want the exception to be thrown.
Instead, I see a `NullPointerException` being thrown:

```
Failed to complete request: java.lang.NullPointerException: while trying to invoke the method 
java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(java.util.function.Supplier) of a null object returned from 
com.sap.gb.service.TenantDatabaseService.findTenantById(java.lang.String)
```

Any help here?

Comment: One of the methods in your chain is returning null instead of an optional.

Comment: Could you please add the stacktrace of the exception

Comment: The new nullpointerexception description message makes it quite obvious: `findTenantById()` returned a null instead of an empty optional

Comment: What's the declaration of `Repository#findById`?

Comment: @daniu I think your deleted answer actually gave the correct solution (unless of course you mean that it's the repository that should be fixed, which I doubt is needed)

Comment: @ernest_k I deleted it because it would have resulted in a compile error if `findById` weren't declared to return an `Optional`, so `findTenantById` would then return an `Optional<Optional<Tenant>>`... or am I missing something?

Comment: @daniu yes :), that's why the optional is being created in your version of `findTenantById` (well, I suppose that's what the OP intended to do, otherwise I don't see what `findTenantById` is adding)

Comment: Either `findById` is declared to return an Optional, in which case it returning null is an error that should be fixed inside that method; or it returns a `Tenant` object, in which case the code in the question would not compile. The information in the question suggests the first case rather than the second.

Comment: When you say "*When `findById` is `null`, I want the exception to be thrown*", you've already defeated the complete purpose of the `Optional` return type there. Do not assign an `Optional` a `null` value ever.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that `tenantRepository.findById(id)` sometimes returns `null` I would adapt it the following way.

```
public Optional<Tenant> findTenantById(String id) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(tenantRepository.findById(id));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with myy jpa implementation and one of the methods in the chain was throwing null as mentioned by many of you. Thanks for all the help.